# How to fetch oldest and newest order for each customer in mysql?

Tags: mysql

This is my `orders` table:

[image]

I want to fetch oldest and newest order for each customer. Here you can see customer 231, 232, etc. have multiple orders. How can we get very first and latest order based on `order_date` for each customer?

So, here I would expect 2 MySQL queries to get required results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `group by customer_id` to get the min and max dates and then join to the table:

```
select o.* 
from orders o inner join (
  select customer_id, min(order_date) mindate, max(order_date) maxdate
  from orders
  group by customer_id
) g on o.customer_id = g.customer_id and (o.order_date in (g.mindate, g.maxdate))
```